# Meaning of Chance Values in "Beat the Dealer's Card" Game

Tags: probability, statistics

###### Question

What do the chance values in the table below mean? I cannot figure out since some of them are `greater than 100%` (doesn't look like a probability).

###### Problem Description

Below is the description of the Bonus Game<sup>A</sup> for which I'm trying to figure out the meaning of the player's chance values:

*A player has to choose a card from the 4 cards. If the player beats the dealer's card, their winnings are doubled and they can try again (up to 10 attempts in total). If the player loses in any round, they lose all their winnings and the Bonus Game ends.*

[image: Cards on table]

**Notes:**

1. The `Joker` beats all other cards.
2. The dealer cannot have a `Joker`.
3. Picking a card of the same value as the dealer's means a draw: the player can take another attempt.
4. The player can take their winnings (in this case, the Bonus Game ends).

The average RTP (Return to Player) is 85%. But, the player's chances can be higher or lower in every round depending on the dealer's card:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A – 40% | K – 61% | Q – 65% | J – 70% | 10 – 85% | 9 – 93% | 8 – 99% |
| 7 – 100% | 6 – 100% | 5 – 100% | 4 – 119% | 3 – 123% | 2 – 165% |  |

---

What do `40% … 165%` values mean?

---

<sup>A</sup> The game description was adapted from a description of a real game.

Comment: Well, it says "return to player", though that's puzzling too.  I'd have thought that this meant something like "how much the player expects to make on a fixed bet", but I can't sort out how, say, the $A-40\%$ works here.  Surely, if the dealer has an Ace, you expect to lose.  Almost all draws are a loss.  So, perhaps the rules aren't clear.

Comment: @lulu I would have thought with a dealer Ace that you win with a Joker (how many Jokers? let's suppose 2) and lose with anything except an Ace or a Joker (48 ways; draws can be ignored since you just turn over another of the four face down cards) so the probability of winning is $4\%$ and the expected return is double that (for a stake of $1$, you end up with $2$ if you win and $0$ if you lose) so $8\%$

Comment: @Henry  So, for a bet of $100$, you expect to lose $96\%$ of the time and to take home $200$ the remaining $4\%$, which makes your expected return very negative.  I get $-88\%$ under your (sensible) assumptions.

Comment: @Henry  I think the rules aren't clear.  What's the point of the $4$ cards?  Choosing one of those is no different than just drawing another card from the deck.  I think the details need clarification.

Comment: @lulu The 4 face-down cards is the only part I understand.  You have to turn one over (your choice which) to resolve the bet; if it differs from the dealer's card then you can resolve the bet, but if equal then you have to turn another one over - and since there are potentially 3 matching cards, you need to start with 4 face down.

Comment: @Henry  But how would that be any different if I was just drawing from the deck?  I get that it can't take me more than $4$ tries to resolve the battle, but it's not like there's any optionality on my part.  I still am just drawing cards blindly and the play is automatic.

Comment: @lulu If the dealer's card is an Ace then I get $8\%$ return where $100\%$ is "fair", or $-92\%$ where $0\%$ is "fair". If the dealer's card is a 2 then I would have thought the player must win so I get $200\%$ return where $100\%$ is "fair", or $+100\%$ where $0\%$ is "fair".  But this does not match the question

Comment: @Henry  I agree with that.  Something seems awry.

Comment: @lulu, I thought about the RTP for a separate card but `5`, `6`, and `7` all have the same values which is strange. Anyway, thank you for your comments!